# Declare an array and initialize it separately

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, declaration

What I want to do:

```
int[] array;

...


array = {2, 7, 9};
```

Is there any way to do this?

Also what is it called when someone declares and initializes at the same time? I just think of it as hard code initializing

Comment: Have your tried to run your code? What happened?

Comment: array = new int[]{2, 7, 9};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
int[] array;
array = new int[] {2, 7, 9};
```